# How to maximize use the GPU on OpenCL?

Tags: opencl, gpu

I use OpenCL on AMD Radeon Vega 64. In the task manager i see that GPU using at 7% max. How to maximize use the GPU?

```
NDRange global(100000);
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, NULL, global));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly through trial and error. Depending on your kernel, the easiest way is to simply increase the global work size. You can also attempt to use available info like `CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS` or `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES` to programmatically determine the work size, but it's not totally reliable.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manually set the work group size to a value that will increase performance. Typically the defaults are good enough, but sometimes you may want to use [clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo.html) to obtain kernel-specific values, such as CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE. The latter can be used as an indication of what a good custom work group size can be for a given OpenCL kernel.